# How can I add code syntax highlighting in a NSTextView using highlighter.js

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, syntaxhighlighter

I am trying to do the code syntax color and parsing with highlighter.js so I can render the markdown with my NSTextView.

I am looking for how I can get started with setting up highlighter.js with my NSTextView.

Please see the below picture of what I am trying to recreate.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Highlightr framework](https://github.com/raspu/Highlightr), which uses highlightr.js to provide syntax highlighting in Swift for iOS and Mac apps.